# Is ‘by’ needed in "I tied myself in knots, by worrying about whether I would be judged by people"?

Tags: prepositions

> I tied myself in knots, by worrying about whether I would be judged by people.

Do you need 'by' in the sentence above?

Comment: IMO, it would be better to say "I tied myself in knots, worrying whether I would be judged by people". But that is just my (non-native) opinion.

Comment: @Sphinx I agree, except that I would drop the comma.

Comment: either have the word 'by' **or** the comma, not both.

Answer (score 1):

Very few words are *required* in a sentence. The sentence in the question could be reduced to a minimum:

*I tied myself in knots worrying about being judged.*

That eliminated "by" "whether" "I" "would" and "by people," and changed "be" to "being." Yet the meaning is almost exactly the same.

So, the word "by" is not absolutely necessary, but it doesn't hurt the meaning, nor make the sentence wordy. However, I would remove the comma:

*I tied myself in knots by worrying about whether I would be judged by people.*